# Transfer *.contact from PC to Samsung Galaxy S 2

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2

How can I transfer my contacts from my PC (win7) .contact (iPhone 4) to Samsung Galaxy S2? I no longer have the iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you are saying, you synced all your iPhone contacts to Windows and have *.contact files in the Contacts folder.

So download [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) and you will be able to sync the contacts from PC to phone.

Alternatively, in Windows export your contacts as a CSV file and then import this into the Gmail/Google account you have linked to your phone. These contacts can then be synced from Google to your phone.

Answer (score 1):

**EASY SOLUTION**

Solution that I found was dumber than expected:

- Make sure the `.contact` files are in your `C:/Users/username/contacts` folder
- Go to Kies, on the top right corner make it "lite mode". (next to the X / close button)
- Click on the Sync TAB
- Sync contacts with Windows Contacts.

Crazy eh!?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to change your iPhone or just want to take backup of your iPhone contacts, here is a simple way to export your iPhone contacts as csv file in Windows 7 and you can open this csv file in Excel. You just need your iPhone and iTunes running in Windows7. Windows XP users here.
Export iPhone contact as CSV file or to Excel
Download and install iTunes, after installation Run iTunes.
Connect your iPhone with computer using data cable.
On the safe side backup your device first, Right-click on your device and select “Back Up” (in-case of any problem with iPhone Contacts you can restore your device later).

When iTunes finish the back up process, Click on “Info” tab

Click on “Sync Contacts with” check box, select “Windows Contacts” from drop down menu and click “Apply” or “Sync” button

Press “Windows + R” keys form keyboard to open “Run” window and type “wab” in “Open” filed and hit OK

Click on tiny arrow and select “Export” as shown below

Select “CSV (Comma Separated Values)” option and click “Export” button

Click on “Browse” button, choose location to save iPhone contacts as csv file

Select iPhone contacts fields that you want to export and hit “Finish” button

You will see this message if iPhone contacts exported as csv file successfully, hit “OK” button.

Now you can use this csv file to import iPhone contacts in any other application or device or you can open this file in Excel to view all iPhone contacts.